# Is OAuth overkill in this situation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ssl, oauth

I have a RoR app that needs to send data to another app via some authenticated, SSL protocol.  The other app is on a Windows stack (in case it matters).  Users will not have access to either endpoint - I need to establish a single, secured endpoint <> endpoint pipe between these two apps (preferably via a web service).  Do you think OAuth should be used in this situation?

I'm a bit new to app development; apologies if this is a bit of a novice question.  Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what your use case is, but OAuth is geared towards allowing external applications access to user data without giving up the user's password, and it's granted by the user.

If you are just sending info back and forth between two servers, you could just use HTTPS and basic auth.